# How Can I Successfully Cast a Multi-Valued Enum?

Tags: c#, parsing, enums, casting, tostring

**Problem:**
I can return the string representation of a single valued `enum` with `enum.ToString()`. In the cases of multi-valued `enum` (e.g.: signified using the `OR` operator `|`), all I get back in the `enum.ToString()` call is the integer value because the `enum` fails to `parse`.

**Work-arounds/Hindrances:**
I can't create multiple instances of the same value in `enum`, such as:

```
public enum Languages: int
{
     English = 0, // From American English
     English = 1, // From UK English
     Spanish = 2, // From Castillian Spanish
     Spanish = 3, // From Latin American Spanish
     Portuguese = 4 // From Brasilian Portuguese
     Portuguese = 5, // From European Portuguese
}
```

as this violates the standard and the IDE gets super frowny-face about that.

**Example of Problem:**

```
public enum Languages: int
{
     English = 0 | 1,   // American or UK
     Spanish = 2 | 3,   // Castillian or Latin American
     Portuguese = 4 | 5,   // Brasil or Portugal
     MyMadeUpLanguage = 6,     
}

int selectedLanguage = 1;
Languages result = (Languages)Enum.Parse(typeof(Languages), selectedLanguage);
string resultString = result.ToString();  // This is where '1' is returned and not English.

int nextSelectedLanguage = 6;
Languages differentResult = (Languages)Enum.Parse(typeof(Languages), nextSelectedLanguage);
string nextResultString = differentResult.ToString();  // This returns 'MyMadeUpLanguage', as we would expect.
```

**Expectations (or what I'm trying to do):**

What I'm expecting is that the conditional should match, so `0` or `1` would match `English` and my enum result would then be `Languages.English` and, so, the string returned would `English` and not `1`.

Instead, what *seems* to happen is that the call to `parse` the `enum` just returns as an `int` and not a `Language` type (referencing the example above), so - of course - the `enum.ToString()` method returns an `int`.

For multi-valued `enum`, where it's possibe that `2` to `x <= int.MaxValue` values will suffice for the `enum`, how can I get the call to `parse` the `enum` to cast successfully to the expected `enum` (which would, resultantly, bring the proper string back in the return of the `enum.ToString()` method)?

Comment: Why not just have US English, UK English (etc) in the enum?

Comment: That's just an example. The real thing that I'm working on is a processor for the Swedish Postnummer (Zip Code) and one of the digits has five different digits which can be supplied for the same value; specifically, in this case, [Brevbäring](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postnummer_i_Sverige#Fempositionsorter).

Maybe chosing language wasn't the best of ideas for the example but it's just an example of the problem that anyone should be able to reproduce, no matter the context of the left-hand of the equal sign.

Comment: Make it a flagged enum and define `[Flags] public enum Languages { English = 1 << 0 || 1 << 1, Spanish = 1 << 2 || 1 << 3, … }`. To check if selectedLanguage is any English do `var isEnglish = (selectedLanguage & Languages.English) != 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Flags` attribute, e.g.:

```
[Flags]
public enum Languages: int
{
     None = 0,                      // None 

     English    = 1 << 30,          // Languages  
     Spanish    = 1 << 29,  
     Portuguese = 1 << 28,   
     MyMadeUpLanguage = 1 << 27, 

                                    // Dialects
     EnglishUS = English | 1,       // From American English
     EnglishGB = English | 2,       // From UK English
     EnglishCA = English | 3,       // From Canada English
     SpanishES = Spanish | 1,       // From Castillian Spanish
     SpanishLA = Spanish | 2,       // From Latin American Spanish
     PortugueseBR = Portuguese | 1, // From Brasilian Portuguese
     PortuguesePT = Portuguese | 2, // From European Portuguese 

     MyMadeUpLanguageDialect1 = MyMadeUpLanguage | 1
}
```

Typical comparisons:

```
Languages selectedLanguage ...

if (Languages.EnglishGB & Languages ==  Languages.EnglishGB) {
  // From Exactly English Great Britain
  ...
}

if (Languages.English & Languages == Languages.English) {
  // From some kind of English (Great Britain, or US dialect)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  @dmitry-bychenko! The bit-shifting (1 << x) was the answer. :)